# What happens with mortgaged properties during bankruptcy?

Tags: monopoly

A player lands on my property and has no cash. They owe me only $26. They have 1 property, a railroad which is mortgaged. The mortgaged value is $100.

Do I get the mortgaged property and have to pay $74 to this other player or is this player out of the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The player is bankrupt and out of the game and you get the mortgaged property with some conditions. You will have to pay the bank 10% of the mortgaged value when you get it and before you unmortgage it if it is not on the same turn.

[Rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf)

> If you have mortgaged property you also turn
>   this property over to your creditor but the new owner must at once
>   pay the Bank the amount of interest on the loan, which is 10% of the
>   value of the property. The new owner who does this may then, at
>   his/her option, pay the principal or hold the property until some later
>   turn, then lift the mortgage. If he/she holds property in this way until
>   a later turn, he/she must pay the interest again upon lifting the
>   mortgage.

Comment: So conversely if this player - let’s say had 4 railroads and all of them are mortgaged - and he lands on my property (and now owes me 26$) and has no cash - do I get all the 4 mortgaged railroads??

Comment: When a player goes bankrupt you get all property they own